# Using mathutils outside of Blender

Tags: python, scripting

I have installed mathutils 2.81.2 in my Python 3.8.5 install to use outside of Blender. However, nothing seems to work. E.g. I cannot create a unit matrix `m = mathutils.Matrix()` and find its components by subscripting it `m[0][0]`. I get `TypeError: 'Matrix' object is not subscriptable.`

Printing it simply returns the default `<mathutils.Matrix object at ...>`.

And trying to multiply two matrices using `@` or a matrix with a vector gives a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for @: 'Matrix' and 'Matrix'`.

Isn't mathutils supposed to work outside of Blender? After all, I can install it fine using pip.

By the way, I have also tried the same on Python 3.7.4 (which was the version used in Blender 2.81). I get the same problems there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working for me. I think you have problem with installation.

[image]

Comment: OK! Thank you! That was indeed the case! Reinstalling python completely solved my problems!

Comment: Actually, reinstalling everything, it turns out that there was an incompatibility problem. The `fake-bpy-module` (which is used to get syntax autocomplete outside of Blender, apparently overrides `import mathutils` and instead just imports a fake version that does nothing.